# Replace all dates with the minimum date corresponding to the month

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe df with columns : Date, Value1, Value. I want to replace all the dates in 'Date' with minimum date corresponding to their month.

The dataframe df that I have:

```
Date      Value1     Value1
1/1/2019    1        4
19/1/2019   3        6
30/1/2019   3        1
5/5/2020    2        10
10/5/2020   6        4
```

The output that I want:

```
Date      Value1     Value1
1/1/2019    1        4
1/1/2019    3        6
1/1/2019    3        1
5/5/2020    2        10
5/5/2020    6        4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `to_datetime()`+`groupby()`+`transform()`:

```
df['Date']=df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format='%d/%m/%Y')
df['Date']=df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.month)['Date'].transform('min')
```

output of `df`:

```
    Date        Value   Value
0   2019-01-01  1       4
1   2019-01-01  3       6
2   2019-01-01  3       1
3   2020-05-05  2       10
4   2020-05-05  6       4
```

**Note:** If you want the initial format then use:

```
df['Date']=df['Date'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```